# OpenID server/provider for Django

Tags: python, django, openid, openid-provider

I am looking for a library to implement on OpenID server in Django. That is, I have my own database of users and need to be my own OpenID provider. I do *not* need to *consume* OpenID like all the Django libraries I've found. Are there any good libraries available?

The one library I found was https://bitbucket.org/romke/django_openid_provider/, but it hasn't been touched for a year. Is it in good shape?

Comment: Hi, I'm in the same situation. What did you do in the end? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I'm using django_openid_provider (v.0.4) in production, and it's performing very nicely.  I've tweaked a few bits here and there for personal preference, but yes, I'd say it's in good shape :)

Answer (score 0):

From [OpenID wiki](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run%20your%20own%20identity%20server) there is [DjangoID](http://trac.nicolast.be/djangoid). I've hadn't tested it but it may help.

I've started looking for a django OpenID solution today, as I see that there are more people interested, maybe we can fork one of this projects and advance in top of that.